# How to get S3 key (path) of a table registered in AWS Glue Data Catalog from Spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

What is the best way to find out full path (S3 key) to the data stored via AWS Glue Data Catalog using Spark (or PySpark)?

For example if I saved data following way:

```
my_spark_dataframe \
    .write.mode("overwrite") '
    .format("parquet") \
    .saveAsTable("database_name.table_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get metadata information of a given table and then extract `Location` portion:

```
full_s3_path = spark_session \
    .sql("describe formatted database_name.table_name") \
    .filter(col("col_name") == "Location") \
    .select("data_type").head()[0]
```

This will return:

```
# full_s3_path=s3://some_s3_bucket/key_to_table_name
```